# not possible to initialise main class package.Main

Tags: java, maven

Hi i'm studying how to use Apache Kafka and when i try to execute my .jar file i get this error:

> Error: Unable to initialise main class kafka.Main Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Producer

I tried to check my dependencies and update them but i can't understand why this is happening.

This is my pom file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org</groupId>
    <artifactId>KafkaApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>kafka.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an executable fat JAR using the [Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html), rather than the JAR plugin. Only then will your dependency classes (such as `KafkaProducer`) be included in the JAR file.

Comment: Or you can provide the client jar (on the classpath) at runtime, but the shaded JAR is the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

The [Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html) mentioned in another answer is not the only way. There's also a manual approach (though not recommended) and the (simpler) [Apache Maven Assembly Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/index.html) described very well in [*How to Create an Executable JAR with Maven*](https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven):

> ### 2.2. Apache Maven Assembly Plugin
>
> The Apache Maven Assembly Plugin allows users to aggregate the project output along with its dependencies, modules, site documentation, and other files into a single, runnable package.
>
> The main goal in the assembly plugin is the *single* goal, which is used to create all assemblies (all other goals are deprecated and will be removed in a future release).
>
> Let's take a look at the configuration in *pom.xml*:
>
> ```
> <plugin>
>    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
>    <executions>
>        <execution>
>            <phase>package</phase>
>            <goals>
>                <goal>single</goal>
>            </goals>
>            <configuration>
>                <archive>
>                <manifest>
>                    <mainClass>
>                        com.baeldung.executable.ExecutableMavenJar
>                    </mainClass>
>                </manifest>
>                </archive>
>                <descriptorRefs>
>                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
>                </descriptorRefs>
>            </configuration>
>        </execution>
>   </executions>
> </plugin>
> ```
>
> Similarly to the manual approach, we need to provide the information about the main class. The difference is that the Maven Assembly Plugin will automatically copy all required dependencies into a *jar* file.
>
> In the *descriptorRefs* part of the configuration code, we provided the name that will be added to the project name.
>
> Output in our example will be named as *core-java-jar-with-dependencies.jar*.
>
> - **pros** – dependencies inside the jar file, one file only
> - **cons** – basic control of packaging our artifact, for example, there is no class relocation support

Comment: The assembly plugin docs explicitly say to use the shade plugin for simple use cases

Comment: @OneCricketeer I interpret "[_If your project wants to package your artifact in an uber-jar, the assembly plugin provides only basic support. For more control, use the Maven Shade Plugin.](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/index.html#Introduction)_" not as "simple use cases". :)